# JSON display method

Tags: html, ajax, json

I have scenario where I could use your help for the best practice and efficient code.

I have a JSON Array like below

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-07-16",
        "DiscPoint": "Description 1",
        "DisBy": "Person 1"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-07-16",
        "DiscPoint": "Description 2",
        "DisBy": "Person 2"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-07-16",
        "DiscPoint": "Description 3",
        "DisBy": "Person 3"
    }
]
```

How do I omit the first element while iterating the JSONArray, Please note I have to omit it only after the first iteration.

I need to display the date for every new date. Please help me out in this scenario.

Comment: I'm not able to post the image, coz I dont have those many reputations

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Comment: What language are you using to iterate over this array?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').fadeIn();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:7001/MOM_Project/service/read", function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      $('table tr:first').after('<tr>  <td style = "width : 100px;">' + value.Date + '</td> <td>' + value.DiscPoint + '</td> <td>' + value.DisBy + '</td> </tr>');
     });
    });
   });`

Comment: I getting this value from rest web service & jQuery to iterate over the array

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by - Please note I have to omit it only after the first iteration.? Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry I haven't explained it properly

Comment: This is how I would like my JSON data to be displayed for the user

Comment: Please visit this link to see how it should be displayed

http://postimg.org/image/h424hr3cz/

Answer (score 0):

In `$.each()` function just add if-statement which will be skipping first index, which is equal to 0.

```
$.each(yourArray, function(index, value) {
    if (index != 0) {
        // do something
    }
});
```